# Looping Datatables Row

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, mysqli

I am doing a reportentry that use datatables which has input entry. The problem is The last row doesnt show up correctly.

this is my datatables,

```
$flightsCount = $_POST['flights'];
<tbody>
                    <?php
                        for($i = 1; $i <= count($flightsCount);$i++){
                            $flightRoute = $mysqli->query("SELECT flight_region FROM mst_flight WHERE flight_id = '$flightsCount[$i]'")->fetch_object()->flight_region;
                            echo "<tr>";
                                echo "<td>$i</td>";
                                echo "<td>GA $flightsCount[$i]</td>";
                                echo "<td>$flightRoute</td>";
                                echo "<td>$newDate</td>";
                                echo "<td><input type='text'/></td>";
                                echo "<td><input type='text'/></td>";
                                echo "<td><input type='text'/></td>";
                            echo "</tr>";
                        }
                    ?>
                </tbody>
```

error message is ,
Notice: Undefined offset: 5 in C:\xampp\htdocs\SOBCASHIER\html\main\divpages\srdetailstab.php on line 34

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\SOBCASHIER\html\main\divpages\srdetailstab.php on line 34

Notice: Undefined offset: 5 in C:\xampp\htdocs\SOBCASHIER\html\main\divpages\srdetailstab.php on line 37

last row only shows GA without showing the code.

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Just start your `for` loop from `0`. like:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($flightsCount);$i++)
```

and to display in `td` just write `$i + 1`.

**Note:** Not able to test this, But hope it should work

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to include the `0` index for $flightsCount

Your code should be updated to :

```
$flightsCount = $_POST['flights'];
<tbody>
                    <?php
                        for($i = 0; $i < count($flightsCount);$i++){
                            $flightRoute = $mysqli->query("SELECT flight_region FROM mst_flight WHERE flight_id = '$flightsCount[$i]'")->fetch_object()->flight_region;
                            echo "<tr>";
                                echo "<td>".($i+1)."</td>";//updated to include the index update
                                echo "<td>GA $flightsCount[$i]</td>";
                                echo "<td>$flightRoute</td>";
                                echo "<td>$newDate</td>";
                                echo "<td><input type='text'/></td>";
                                echo "<td><input type='text'/></td>";
                                echo "<td><input type='text'/></td>";
                            echo "</tr>";
                        }
                    ?>
                </tbody>
```